# Get Web Author in Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, csom, web

Server API provides [SPWeb.Author](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.author.aspx) property to access the creator of the site. However, managed client object model [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_properties.aspx) doesn't seem to provide any such property. What is the alternative to get the author of the web object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var spWeb = context.Site.OpenWeb("Test");
var creator = spWeb.Author;
```

Update the CSOM dll to the latest one or atleast August 2016 version. The author property is exposed. You can use it as above.

[SharePoint CSOM version released for SharePoint Online - August 2016](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated)